# XPath to only select the text contained within an element

Tags: xpath

I am new to xpath so I apologize in advance for how basic this question is.

How do I extract just the text from a specific element? For example, how would I extract just "text"

```
<h1>text</h1>
```

I tried the following but it seems to select everything including the  tags instead of just the text.

```
//h1/text()
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Certainly it doesn't select any tags, because tags are not objects available for selection: there are no tags on the source tree, only nodes. It would help if you describe the symptoms that have led you to this incorrect diagnosis of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
`
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File("src/myFile.xml"));

            XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();

             String sessionId = (String) xpath
    .evaluate(
                            "/Envelope/Body/LoginProcessResponse/loginResponse/sessionId",
                            doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
`
```

here Envelope is my parent element and i just traversed to the required path(in my case it is sessionid).
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This answer is rather an XSLT answer than an XPath answer, but many of the concepts are nevertheless applicable.

The XPath expression

```
//h1/text()
```

seems to be correct. It does select all `text()` nodes that are direct children of `<h1>` elements.

But one problem may be, that the XSL default template still copies all the other`text()` nodes like described [here in the W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Applying-Template-Rules):

> In the absence of a select attribute, the xsl:apply-templates instruction processes all of the children of the current node, including text nodes.

So to solve your problem, you have to define an explicit template that
**ignores all other text() nodes** like this:

```
<xsl:template match="text()" />
```

If you add this line to your XSL processing, the result will most likely be more pleasant to you.